# TypeScript compile and keep comments

Tags: typescript, tsc

I like to have my comments intact in the resulting javascript file, by default the compiler removes them. Is there a tsc parameter for that? (The use case is to keep /// reference path's = ... for chutzpah unit testing. )

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I also found the option in Web Essentials Tools>Options>Web Essentials> Keep Comments , now testing is easy : http://joeriks.com/2012/10/06/testing-typescript-with-chutzpah/

Comment: Now Chutzpah supports Typescript ootb which is great, see answer by Matthew Manela below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, the -c (or --comments) option;

> Syntax:   tsc [options] [file ..]
>
> Examples: tsc hello.ts
>             tsc --out foo.js foo.ts
>             tsc @args.txt
>
> Options:
>      **-c, --comments        Emit comments to output**
>   ...

Comment: Which version introduces it? I get `error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'comments'.` for `1.0.3.0` and `1.5.0-alpha`

Comment: Comments starting with a !, such as /*! comment */ are preserved. This is helpful when you want only some comments to remain in the js transpiled file

Answer (score 27):

Since 2015 you can create a `tsconfig.json` in your project and add `"removeComments": false` to its `"compilerOptions"` property in order to keep your comments in the resulting javascript files.

---

#### 1. Create the `tsconfig.json` file for your project from your terminal (if necessary)

```
tsc -init
```

#### 2. Add `"removeComments": false` to your `tsconfig.json` file inside the `"compilerOptions"` property

At the end, you should expect your `tsconfig.json` file content to be like this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "sourceMap": false,
        "removeComments": false
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

#### 3. Compile your .ts file into a .js file from your terminal

- Use `tsc myFile.ts` in order to keep your comments
- Use `tsc --removeComments myFile.ts` in order to remove your comments

---

You can learn more about `tsconfig.json` compiler options on [Typescriptlang.org tsconfig.json page](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html).

Furthermore, according to the [Typescript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html), setting `true` or `false` to the `"removeComments"` property will have no effect on copy-right header comments beginning with `/*!`. Thus, they will always appear in your `.js` files.

Comment: This won't work for type/code not going to be emitted in the JS output:  https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1665

Answer (score 17):

Comments that start with `/*!` are preserved.

**example:**
`/*! this comment remains untouched */`
`/* but this one will be removed */`

Comment: tested in tsc 1.5(alpha)

Comment: I was not able to repro this in tsc 1.5.3.

Comment: I don't know if this is out of date, but it's only the header comment with `/*!` that will be kept, with the `removeComments` option enabled. All others will be removed.

Comment: Do you know where this is mentioned in official documents?

Comment: It is mentioned here under "--removeComments": https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Answer (score 9):

Currently using 1.6.2 and it appears comments are preserved by default. The only comment-related flag in the compiler is to *remove* comments. As per the docs:

> --removeComments
>   Remove all comments except copy-right header comments beginning with /!*

Answer (score 4):

You will have to edit the underlying .csproj file and include the -c option.
Have a look here:

http://blorkfish.wordpress.com/2012/10/06/including-typescript-comments-in-generated-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

[Chutzpah 2.2](http://chutzpah.codeplex.com/) now supports TypeScript natively so you don't need to worry about this. You can run Chutzpah directly on the .ts file and it will run your tests.